# Passing amount from user to braintree server

Tags: meteor, braintree

This Meteor code uses patrickml:braintree, since I do not have access to the braintree submit event in order to send a price to the server for processing.

How can I pass an $$ amount from a html element on the page where the client is clicking to the server?

```
//client
Template.account.onRendered(function () { //6a
  Meteor.call('getClientToken', function (error, clientToken) {
    if (!error) {
      braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
        container: "payment-form",
        onPaymentMethodReceived: function (response) {
          var nonce = response.nonce;
          Meteor.call('btCreateCustomer', function(error) {
            if (error) {
              throw new Meteor.Error('customer-creation-failed');
            } else {
              Meteor.call('createTransaction', nonce, function (error) {
                if (error) {
                  throw new Meteor.Error('transaction-creation-failed');
                }
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<template name="account">
  <div id="account">
    <p>Select invoice period:</p>
    <select class={{this.class}} data-id={{_id}} name={{name}}>
      {{#each values}}
        <option class={{class}} selected={{selected}} name={{name}} value={{value}}>{{{label}}}</option>
      {{/each}}
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <form role="form">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
          <div id="payment-form"></div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: You get the value from the DOM via `getElementById` and pass the value to the server by including it in your Meteor call as a parameter.

Comment: That is good and general which I understand, but I do not have access to the Braintree submit button event in the Meteor template, do I?

Comment: Run the Braintree portion of your code in your event handler function instead of the onRender template function. You won't have access to the submit button on the `onRendered` event, since it just fires only once when the DOM elements are ready.

Comment: BrainTree `Submit` button gets clicked, then it starts its magic. If I put the the Brainstree "posted" code in the Meteor template event handler, then clicking the Braintree `Submit` button will fire the Meteor event handler??? so any Meteor event will work??? could you please show in code? thx